# Ternary relationships in coreData

Tags: ios, core-data, entity, relationship, ternary

Lets say I have entities Article, Page and Category.
I want entity Article to have a relationship like this.
Article (A1) has a category (C1) for page (P1), but I want the same article (A1) to have a category (C2) for another page (P2).

How do I model this in coreData? I'm guessing maybe one of these relationships doesn't have to implement its inverse relationship, but I'm not sure about that.
Any ideas?

Comment: Your use of A, B and C is probably more confusing than if you gave real examples that people can relate to.

Comment: yeah... my bad. Just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not have the `page` entity keep track of it's `category`?

You could then provide a method on `article` that loops through all the `page`'s and returns an `NSSet` of `category`'s. If this was to be used often you could consider caching the result

**Update**

```
                      +----------+
                      | Category |              
                      +----------+
                            |
                            V
+---------+         +--------------+         +------+
| Article | <---->> | CategoryPage | <<----> | Page |
+---------+         +--------------+         +------+
```

- An `article` can have many `pages` through `category_page`
- A `page` can belong to many `articles` through `category_page`

I don't think you can simply do

```
+---------+         +------+
| Article | <<--->> | Page |
+---------+         +------+
```

because you also need the `category` information

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that. But category is a property of articles not pages.

Comment: Yup I am saying why is it a property of `Article`? Why can't the `Page`'s keep track of their category

Comment: Its not category as I think you're thinking. This category represents lets say wether the article is a top headline or not. Its not category like Art, Games, etc

Comment: so an article can be a top headline for one page but it may not be a top headline for another page

Comment: So I have to model that relationship like an entity? There's no way of setting it as a relationship between page/category/article ?